# Database-Write Intensive Web Application

Tags: php, c++, database, oracle, performance

**TLDR**
Would moving a PHP application's logic to a C++ daemon that interacts with an OracleDB be a smart move?

I created a simple application for one of the teams at our company, basically they audit transactions made and mark any errors/incompleteness they find.

Initially it was PHP Apachemod + MYSQL running on a Virtual CentOS with 15 users. MYSQL was hogging the CPU at multiple times. Since then I've moved it to PHP-FPM & oracle.

The queries have been optimized and indexes created correctly and where needed.

The application has about 16 users simultaneously, each expected to audit around 350 transaction a day. Write operations are almost each second, with every transaction requiring an insert in about 4 tables. The DB structure is currently one large database (no partitioning, no caching). On a daily basis about 70K new transactions are added to the database, and as of today  there are > 1M transactions.

Users sometimes witness delay since the PHP side needs to complete the DB write before returning.

I was thinking that this could be improved by:

- Move to a dedicated server
- Optimizing the DB first (partition - log and tmp, monthly partitions)
- Create an archiving structure to move previous quarters transactions and user operations
- Maybe move SQL to stored procedures?
- Create C++ daemon that looks for audit details (thinking could be a file based event ie. looks for a file and loads the records appropriately)
  -- could be then made as a PHP library
- PHP utilizes Gearman to send details to input directory of C++. Or maybe use memcached.

This way the PHP frontend could immediately return to the user once it passed the details to memcached/gearman which i hope would be faster than a DB write.

What other options are there? Is this overcomplicating the problem? And yes, the team leader has complained over 2second delays. ("premature optimization is the root of all evil" does not apply here)

Comment: How resp. where is this `transaction [...] an insert in about 4 tables` implemented?

Comment: btw - `Maybe move SQL to stored procedures` - where is the better part of your `SQL` located now?

Comment: @christian Tldr seems to short, I'll fix it when I'm on my laptop - meant to give users an idea what the long version is about in case the title isn't that clear.

Comment: @decltype_auto stored in the model of the php. Actual sql statements + pdo.

Comment: And why not simply try and delegate that to sps and views in the database? If it's already well structured in the PHP code (e.g. SQL command strings stored centrally and not meshed up with the PHP function code), the migration should not be too difficult a task.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Your application is system write bound at the moment.

One might ask if the transaction processing really needs to be synchronous or can also be dealt with asynchronously (think message queue).

Otherwise I'd see two reasonable paths of action

1. Separate the persistence layer from the application layer, i.e: Host the DB on a dedicated machine with better write throughput.
2. Review the actual persistence schema of Your application, 2s for four writes sounds like You are doing very expensive writes.

Regarding C++ and Stored Procedures I don't see potential for high returns as it seems the problem is nearer to Hardware bounds or Business rules than it is to the used technology.

Comment: Let's take the questioner's term 'move SQL to stored procedures' as a synonym for 'pushing logic downwards into the DB',  that could well bring a performance boost, last not least because the workload is no longer ping-ponged back and forth between the DB and the PHP layer..

Comment: Yeah that was the idea, move sql to db, and in terms of the c++, kee a daemon with a persistent db connection that handles the writes and logic. Php becomes a simple front end that handle forms and Ajax requests.

Comment: The idea of custom "data servers" constituting a layer above the DBMS is wide spread and sound fancy, but has to be considered twice. The DBMS does many things better than one substitute it manually; esp if its an Oracle.

Comment: @decltype_auto pushing logic downwards into the RDBMS is a double edged sword. We don't know if user687976 means business logic or just technical logic. It generally isn't advised to push the first out of the application layer because you set yourself up with bad concern isolation. As to the "data servers" You mention, I'm not sure I can follow, my proposition is to just give the RDBMS a chance to utilise system resources without having the noise and evtl. confinements of other applications. Pooled connections is a reasonable idea, how much time goes into connection handling now?

Comment: @KiriakosKrastillis 'pushing logic downwards into the RDBMS is a double edged sword' And plain (table)1:1(class) ORM is a double edged sword even without a hilt; the you more delegate upwards, the more effort has to be spent to keep the model in sync with the model's constraints. Of course aside from the fact that it tends to ping-pong the data over and over and over....

Comment: @decltype_auto while I understand and support Your response I fail to see how this is relevant here. Keeping business logic and technical logic in their respective layers is a well supported best practice. No one spoke about pushing upwards but yes, delegating downwards even the the technical layer will make for bad system architecture. In the end either You accuse the asker of doing his ORM wrong (for which there is no evidence) or You suggest that the application needs a better persistence protocol which is what I do elaborate my original answer.

Comment: It's a misconception that clean separation of layers implied any form of physical separation of the respective implementation during runtime -  it's not automatically part of  what you 'technical logic' because it resides in the RDBMS. Moreover, it's a trivial and well-known fact that a good part of the business logic can and should be implemented in views and stored procedures if it's data-centric application like this; that's basic application design knowledge.

Comment: @decltype_auto that's very thin. This debate has lost all relevance to the question and I won't indulge in it any longer.